# Java libraries which are not binaries?

Tags: java, eclipse, binary, zip, bin

I have seen some java libraries that are zips with source code in them, and when I try to add them to my build path of my project it just doesn't recognize the classes. Should I just copy-paste the library's folder to the src folder of my project, or i have to do something to get the library as binaries?

Comment: When do you have the source code, you could complie them by yourself, make a library and add them to your build path. Alternative, like your idea, you can copy it in your project. (But i would take them into a sub-package, just for the struktur)

Comment: You should learn to use Maven or Gradle, which will manage all of this for you (including automatically finding and attaching source code for most of your libraries so you can examine what they do).

Comment: +0x4Dark compile? how? javac? javac needs a main class. and this could have been an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a jar files for java source code and then export it in your project settings.